# Can I do a trend analysis with just 4 years of data?

Tags: r, test-for-trend

I have proportions of health service use (several different types) across 4 years. All types of health services appear to be increasing over time.
I wonder if it is possible to do a trend analysis with just 4 data points... (and if so, which test should be used?)
Each year contains between 20k-40k subjects, and my analysis is for descriptive purposes.

Comment: descriptive statistics does not need test.

Comment: I would like to be able to say there is an upward trend - any help?